# Where will the jar be loaded up from in this situation?

Tags: java, jar, jms, classpath, manifest

This site:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.doc%2Fjm10330_.htm

says that

> The manifest of the JAR file com.ibm.mqjms.jar contains references to
>   most of the other JAR files required by WebSphere MQ classes for JMS
>   applications, and so you do not need to add these JAR files to your
>   class path.

So in the MANIFEST of my jar I have the following manifest classpath:

```
Class-Path: /opt/mqm/java/lib/com.ibm.mqjms.jar
```

In the com.ibm.mqjms.jar, it contains the following MANIFEST classpath

```
Class-Path: jms.jar com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar dhbcore.jar rmm.jar jndi.jar l
 dap.jar fscontext.jar providerutil.jar CL3Export.jar CL3Nonexport.jar
```

My question is:  when the com.ibm.mqjms.jar starts looking for the jms.jar (or other jar),
where will it be looking ?  (or at least looking first?

In the jar file itself,or on the /opt/mqm/java/lib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be looking in the directory where com.ibm.mqjms.jar is present. This makes it easier for the user as one need not know the dependencies of com.ibm.mqjms.jar ... Just ensure that you don't move individual jars out of that directory.

Some more details here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html